# Can you add a wild card to a completed book?

Tags: hand-and-foot

In Hand and Foot, after completing a melded book, can you add a wild card to it?  For example, once you have completed a book, but have a wild card left in your hand, can you add the wild card to a previously completed book, in order to go into your Foot or to go out?

Answer (score 1):

According to Pagat.com:

> A meld cannot contain more than seven cards, and a partnership is not allowed to have two incomplete melds of the same rank, but if you complete a pile, you can then start another meld of the same rank.

So not only can you not add a wild card, you cannot add *any* card. You'll need to attach it to another meld in progress, or make a new one.